# How to end a sound right away?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm working on an IOS game, and the background music clip is 7 seconds long, so when the scene changes from one scene to the next, I want it to stop instantly, but it continues and finishes the 7 second loop then stops. 
This is the code:

```
    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"sound 1.m4a" waitForCompletion:YES]]];
    if (_dead == YES) {

        [self removeAllActions];
    }
```

where `_dead` is when the player dies, and the new scene is triggered.

How can I get the music to stop that instant, as opposed to finishing its loop?

Comment: Didn't you have a similar topic with the exact same lines of code a few days ago?  I wouldn't answer a topic with that little information.

Comment: Well what info is needed I would assume this would be the only info because this is the only piece of code that deals with the playing of the background music, and yes I had a similar topic with the same code, and I'm asking again because noone had a solution @ElTomato

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using SKAction to play your background sound file, I would suggest using AVFoundation which allows you to simply issue a `stop` command.

Update

I can't think of any food tutorials that focus primarily on the sound side. Most deal with video and sound. Try google with something like 'AVFoundation tutorial'.

To use AVFoundation you can do this for your purposes...

Add the AVFoundation.framework to your project.

In your .h file add the delegate `<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>`

In your .m file `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

Create a property `AVAudioPlayer *_backgroundMusicPlayer;`

Create this method:

```
- (void)playBackgroundMusic:(NSString *)filename {
NSError *error;
NSURL *backgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:filename withExtension:nil];
_backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
_backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
_backgroundMusicPlayer.volume = 0.2;
_backgroundMusicPlayer.delegate = self;
[_backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
[_backgroundMusicPlayer play];
}
```

To start playing `[self playBackgroundMusic:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bgMusic.mp3"]];`

To stop playing `[_backgroundMusicPlayer stop];`

That should do the trick. I suggest you read up on the AVAudioPlayer Class Reference so you understand its properties. For example, `numberOfLoops` set to -1 will loop the sound indefinitely until you call the `stop` method. Another issue to keep in mind is the audio file sound format. AVFoundation is somewhat picky about what sound files it will play. I always stick to mp3.

Fuzzygoat also makes an excellent point. I have not tried his approach in regards to sound so I do not know if it will solve your issue. It is similar to what you already have but with a slight change.

To start the sound:

```
SKAction *mySound = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"astroKitty 1.m4a" waitForCompletion:YES]];
[self runAction:mySound withKey:@"boogieDown"];
```

To stop the sound:

```
[self removeActionForKey:@"boogieDown"];
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you run into any issues implementing the AVFoundation, leave a comment here.

Comment: Sorry to bother, @sangony but do you know any good tutorials for this ?

Comment: I too would suggest AVAudioFoundation but  if you want to use SKAction you can create the action with a key and remove the action (via  the key) on the next iteration of the update loop.